# sps 2003 migration to moss 2007

Tags: site-collection, migration, upgrade, 2003, content-migration

Hi I am trying to migrate a sps 2003 web app to a moss 2007 server.
The sps 2003 is running on windows server 2003 32bit with MSSQL 2000 and the new moss 2007 is running on windows server 2008 r2 64bit with MSSQL 2005 64bit.

I followed the Microsoft documentation on SharePoint migration from 2003 to 2007 by backing up and restoring the SQL site content database but when i go to view the site nothing appears. i think it is to do with site collections but not sure. i have checked iis and it is working fine.

If anyone has any knowledge of this migration process and can help me i would be very gratefully

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell to be honest without looking. Also I am curious as to why you are migrating to 2007 today. You should look into SharePoint 2013.
Check out tools to do the migration sometimes it can be a lot more cost effective.
http://en.share-gate.com has a free trial for 15 days that could probably get you migrated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SharePoint StackExchange Benjamin. We've all stumbled across ShareGate from time to time, and we get help from your blog. The tool you're referring to is a commercial product, which is out of scope of this site (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). However, you do have valid points in your answer, and I think your reasoning is very accurate. I hope you'll help the community by answering other questions without referencing commercial third party tools. Once again, a warm welcome to SP.SE!

Comment: Saw your Tweet and yes I will answer :) In this case I am honestly providing the best answer I can since no one seemed to have any guidance. The OP knows and did the right steps for a migration unfortunately it's hard to debug. Simply suggesting a free way of doing it if it can fit in the 15 days of the trial. But yes I understand where you are coming from and will be more vigilant. I am happy to hear you found help from the blog. You may notice that the blog often doesn't cover anything related to the product. Really just trying to help.

Comment: Splendid! Your blog is a great source of information, which as you say doesn't reference the product. I know you're trying to help otherwise the blog wouldn't exist. That's why I'm trying to guide you the best way I can in our community rules. I hope that you'll find SP.SE fun and challenging with the gamification aspect of things with real world issues we face every day. I find it great you're trying to help, and hope you'll keep posting here whenever you find the time. Welcome onboard!